# I need your help to find this article

Tags: reference-request

I need this article, I tried to find it somewhere but nothing, I really need your help.

A. Lerat and R. Peyret, Rech. Aerosp. 2(1975) 61—79

Maybe it's written in French, no problem, I still need it. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What's the name of the article?

Comment: I think it's in french: Proriétés dispersives et dissipatives d'une classe de schémas aux différences pour les systèmes hyperboliques non linéaires

Comment: According to a NATO report AGARD-AG-212 that cites this publication, that is the correct name, except it should be "Propriétés ..."

Comment: From what I can find, *La Recherche aérospatiale* was a bi-monthly bulletin published by ONERA, so six issues per year. No luck so far tracking down the relevant issue in the BNF catalogue (my knowledge of French is very limited so I have trouble navigating the site).